# Snowflake SQL How to get only values from the last full week

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to build a query that would get me only the results with a created date from the last full week.
So, for example, if today is Monday 2021-06-28, I only want the results from Monday 2021-06-21 to Sunday 2021-06-27.

I tried with this, but this is the last 7 days, without considering week end or start.

```
WHERE (CREATED_AT::DATE BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE::DATE - INTERVAL '1 WEEK') AND CURRENT_DATE::DATE)
```

I also tried working with this function:

```
last_day(CREATED_AT::DATE, 'week') as "LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK"
```

and then trying to substract 7 days, but I think my use of these functions is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `date_trunc()`:

```
WHERE CREATED_AT >= DATE_TRUNC('week', CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '7 DAY' AND
      CREATED_AT < DATE_TRUNC('week', CURRENT_DATE)
```

Comment: DATE_TRUNC is a really nice approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
WHERE CREATED_AT::DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, '1900-01-01'::DATE, CURRENT_DATE())-1,'1900-01-01'::DATE)
  AND DATEADD(d, 6, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, '1900-01-01'::DATE, CURRENT_DATE())-1,'1900-01-01'::DATE))
```

The weeks are calculated:

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, 
              DATEDIFF(wk, '1900-01-01'::DATE, CURRENT_DATE())-1,
              '1900-01-01'::DATE) AS prev_week,
       DATEADD(d, 6, prev_week) AS current_week
/*
PREV_WEEK   CURRENT_WEEK
2021-06-21  2021-06-27
*/
```